# Configure clang-check for c++ standard libraries

Tags: c++11, clang++

I am trying to run Ale as my linter, which in turn uses clang-check to lint my code.

```
$ clang-check FeatureManager.h
Error while trying to load a compilation database:
Could not auto-detect compilation database for file "FeatureManager.h"
No compilation database found in /home/babbleshack/ or any parent directory
json-compilation-database: Error while opening JSON database: No such file or directory
Running without flags.
/home/babbleshack/FeatureManager.h:6:10: fatal error: 'unordered_map' file not found
#include <unordered_map>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
Error while processing /home/babbleshack/FeatureManager.h.
```

Whereas compiling with clang++ returns only a warning.

```
$ clang++ -std=c++11 -Wall FeatureManager.cxx FeatureManager.h
clang-5.0: warning: treating 'c-header' input as 'c++-header' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
```

There are no flags to clang-check allowing me to set compilation flags.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Took a while to figure this out, but you can do

`clang-check file.cxx -- -Wall -std=c++11 -x c++`

or if you are using clang-tidy

`clang-tidy file.cxx -- -Wall -std=c++11 -x c++`

To get both  working with ALE, I added the following to my vimrc

`let g:ale_cpp_clangtidy_options = '-Wall -std=c++11 -x c++'
let g:ale_cpp_clangcheck_options = '-- -Wall -std=c++11 -x c++'`

If you want ALE to work for C as well, you will have to do the same for `g:ale_c_clangtidy_options` and `g:ale_c_clangcheck_options`.

Comment: Is there a way to force clang check to consider a file as a C++ file. For instance I have a header file which includes `<list>` however clang-check errors with `invalid argument '-std=c++11' not allowed with 'C'`?

Comment: Oh! Good catch @Babbleshack! I got this to work by adding the `-x c++` flag. I'll update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks for this, Where did you find the man pages for clang-check/tidy btw?

Comment: I didn't have any man pages for clang-check/tidy, but you can use `clang-check --help` or `clang-tidy --help` for some help pages. However they don't mention using `--` (there is a very brief mention of it here http://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/). Basically my (limited) understanding of it is that options after the `--` flag are passed along as options to the clang compiler, you can see these options with `man clang`. It would help if the documentation was better though...

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wasted one day in trying to make the linting work, and your answer did it finally.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting stumped by a similar error message for far too long:

```
/my/project/src/util.h:4:10: error: 'string' file not found [clang-diagnostic-error]
#include <string>
         ^
```

I saw other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26333823/113632) suggesting that I was missing some critical package, but everything already seemed to be installed (and my code *built* just fine, it was only `clang-tidy` that was getting upset).

Passing `-v` showed that my `.h` file was being handled differently:

```
$ clang-tidy ... src/*.{h,cc} -- ... -v
...
clang-tool ... -main-file-name util.cc ... -internal-isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9 ... -x c++ ... /tmp/copy/src/util_test.cc
...
clang-tool ... -main-file-name util.h ... -x c-header /my/project/src/util.h
...
```

As Kris notes the key distinction is the `-x c-header` flag, which is because [clang assumes a `.h` file contains C, not C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19413311/113632), and this in turn means that the system C++ includes weren't being used to process `util.h`.

But the `-main-file-name` flag also stood out to me as odd; why would a header file ever be the main file? While digging around I also came across [this short but insightful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23534409/113632) that header files shouldn't be directly compiled in the first place! Using `src/*.cc` instead of `src/*.{h,cc}` avoids the problem entirely by never asking Clang to try to process a `.h` on its own in the first place!

This does introduce one more wrinkle, though. Errors in these header files won't be reported by default, since they're not the files you asked `clang-tidy` to look at. This is where the "*Use -header-filter=.* to display errors from all non-system headers.*" message `clang-tidy` prints comes in. If I pass `-header-filter=src/.*` (to only include my `src` headers and not any other header files I'm including with `-I`) I see the expected errors in my header files. Phew!

I'm not sure whether to prefer `-x c++` or `-header-filter=.*` generally. A downside of `-header-filter` is you have to tune the filter regex, rather than just passing in the files you want to check. But on the other hand processing header files in isolation is essentially wasteful work (that I expect would add up quickly in a larger project).